# Modular arithmetic calculation $366^3\pmod {391}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$366^3\pmod{391}$ Is there an easy way to calculate this without a calculator?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I can't see the message above. Sorry.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat The close reasons are shown differently to users who can vote to close/reopen and differently to those who can't. See also: [Why are specific close reasons no longer shown to users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345078) and [New changes to close reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31544).

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $366^3 = (391-25)^3 = -25^3 \pmod {391}$. You can take it from here...

Answer (score 3):

Since $391=17\cdot 23$ and $366\equiv 9\pmod{17},366\equiv -2\pmod{23}$, we have:
$$ 366^3 \equiv 15\pmod{17},\qquad 366^3\equiv -8\equiv 15\pmod{23}, $$
hence:
$$ 366^3\equiv \color{red}{15}\pmod{391}.$$

Comment: $\ 391 = 20^2-3^2 = (20-3)(20+3) = 17\cdot 23\ $ by difference of squares. Without such a quick way to factor, this way would be *much* more work than computing $\ (-25)^3.\,$ Probably it is still more work even knowing the factorization. But it is instructive as an example of modular reduction.